# Adding Multiple GET Requests to NSMutableArray in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsurlconnection

The app keeps score during a game.  Based off of your score, it will retrieve a quote from an online database, using a GET method and returning it in JSON format.  For example, your score is 5, you get 1 quote, 10, you get 2 and so on.  The view that shows the quote(s) is a `UIViewController` with a `UITextView` in it.

I have a `for loop` that runs based off the score, to run the same GET request over and over again, after a 1.5 second delay so the server housing the database won't reject requests made nearly simultaneously.

I create a few NSStrings and pull information from the JSON data, append it into some basic HTML code and then set that as the `UITextView attributedText`.

Most of the time this runs great, but every once in a while, I'll expect 2 quotes, and only get 1, or some of the quotes will wind up being the same.

Can someone tell me if there is a better way to go about doing this than how I currently am?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger getReady = [defaults integerForKey:@"after"];
    self.theNumber = getReady;
   for(int i = 0; i< self.theNumber; i++) {
       [self performSelector:@selector(quoteView) withObject:self afterDelay:1.5 ];
    }
    }

}
-(void) quoteView {




    NSString *bringitalltogether = @"http://url.com&type=json";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bringitalltogether]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

        if (code == 200){

        }

        else
        {
            UIAlertView *oops = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"The network is having difficulties getting you the quote.  Please check your network settings and try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [oops show];
        }

    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSMutableDictionary *allResults = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                                       options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                       error:nil];
    NSArray *book = [allResults valueForKey:@"bookname"];
    self.bookstring = [book objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *chapter = [allResults valueForKey:@"chapter"];
    self.chapterstring = [chapter objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *verse = [allResults valueForKey:@"verse"];
    self.versestring = [verse objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *text = [allResults valueForKey:@"text"];
    self.textstring = [text objectAtIndex:0];

    [self doneGotIt];
   }
- (void) doneGotIt {
    if (!self.theArray) {

        self.theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }


    NSString *doIt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ %@:%@", self.textstring, self.bookstring, self.chapterstring, self.versestring];
    [self.theArray addObject:doIt];
    NSString *theEnd = [self.theArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

    NSString *loadHTML = [@"<head> <style type='text/css'>a > img {pointer-events: none;cursor: default;}</style></head><b><div align=\"left\"><font size=5>"  stringByAppendingString:theEnd];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[loadHTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    textView.attributedText = attributedString;
    NSLog(@"ARRAY:  %@", self.theArray);
    NSLog(@"String:  %@", theEnd);

}
-(IBAction)finished {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    textView = nil;
}
```

From the `NSLogs` I have towards the end there, sometimes the `NSMutableArray` contains several of the same quotes, which is why they don't show in the string, because it eliminates duplicates.  My question is if there is a better way to do this that will keep these errors from occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code for you

```
mutableArray = new NSMutableArray
while([mutableArray count] < total) {
   quote = getQuote()
   if([array indexOfObject:quote] != NSNotFound) 
      [mutableArray addObject:quote]
}
```

This will ensure you do not have duplicate quotes. After you have an array of valid quotes, you can then construct the string exactly how you want it.

Comment: Is this something I could put in the doneGotIt section where I currently init the array?  And what would quote be equal to?

Comment: I get what you're saying, just trying to reconcile it all into what I have already set up.

Comment: `getQuote()` is the REST call to the server to get a quote. Remember that I wrote pseudo code.